# In what ways was the "Hong Kong Agreement" infringed upon?

Tags: history, block-size-increase

There is a favorite talking point in some parts of the community claiming that this or that party broke the [Hong Kong Agreement](https://medium.com/@bitcoinroundtable/bitcoin-roundtable-consensus-266d475a61ff).

Mentioned are for example:

- Delivery time of SegWit
- Delivery time of hardfork code
- Signaling for Classic

What infringements of the agreement where there, when did they take place and how clear is it that there was a breach in the agreement?

Comment: Is there any written agreement besides what's posted on the @bitcoinroundtable medium account? Seems kind of bare.

Comment: @NickODell: I believe that's it.